Are we slow on answering mods from other sites?
According to this meta question on Philosophy, it seems that we are slow on replying requests from mods of other sites. Is this correct?

I always try to respond to summoning in chats. In this case, I haven't seen their request. I'll try to find out what happened. Many thanks for bringing this up. I've placed comments to the mod's answers over on Phil.

hmm, I thought that there is a special channel between mods to discuss migrations. Pinging individual mods seems ineffective for me.

That said, I feel in case of no response an actual migration is still to be preferred. Asking for migration is etiquette, not mandatory anymore.

Ooker - there is indeed - it is a [closed] chat room.

Short answer
No we are not - you assumed we (i.e., the mod team of Psych&Neurosci) were contacted, and we were not.
Background
I commented in your linked Phil Meta post:

AliceD - My apologies for our unresponsiveness. I pretty much always respond to summons in the teacher's lounge - but this question was not brought t[o] my attention. There are three other mods on Psych&Neurosci and I doubt all of us decided not to react, and again, I haven't seen any summons on this Q. How did the mod team from Philosophy try to contact us?

One of the mods over at Phil responded with 

  - Unintentionally I failed to respond to the request for migration. I take full responsibility for this. I have as you will have seen apologised to the OP and suggested how to put the situation right. In future I will follow the inter-mod procedures. Best -

and 

I apologise that I did not contact. My assumption was that the questioner would her/ himself apply to Psy with the question without my going through a mediation process. I now understand the procedures and the problem will not happen again. I don't suggest and never have suggested that Psy did not respond to a contact. Best ####

I conclude that you assumed we were contacted, and we were not. While we mods are of course brilliant, even we cannot respond to a request that has never been made ;-)

That last part :D

@Ooker - just to see if you were reading my whole answer :)
